# Namespace "http://tempuri.org/" en WebService

Tags: webservice

Al crear un Web Service con Asp.net C# me aparece lo siguiente

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

Luego cuando lo estoy usando me muestra el mensaje:

```
This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace

Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.
```

Cuál es la función de namespace porque no veo que varie en nada al web service. Es necesario cambiarlo, qué deberia poner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando creas un WS, el namespace default es:

http://tempuri.org/

si obtienes el mensaje:

> This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default
>   namespace.
>
> Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web
>   service is made public.

Te sugiere cambiar el namespace para diferenciar tu WebService de los demás.

La misma página que genera el mensaje te debe sugerir esto para C# :

```
C#

[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public class MyWebService {
    // implementation
}
```

Cuando implementes tu Web Service, en la propiedad `Namespace` define un dominio propio por ejemplo:

```
[WebService(Namespace="http://ricotti.com/webservices/")]
    public class MyWebService {
...
...
```

de esta forma cambiaras el Namespace default y cuando revises el WSDL de tu WebService podras ver:

```
...
targetNamespace="http://ricotti.com/webservices/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ricotti.com/webservices/">
...
...
```

Comment: ¿El cambio de namespaces del webservice afecta la forma de invocarlo? Es decir si cambio http://tempuri.org/ de desarrollo a www.unam.mx en producción, ¿eso afecta la forma (la uri) en que debo invocar el webservice?

Comment: No cambia la forma de invocarlo, para invocarlo vas a tener que usar la url con extension .asmx o depende con que lo hagas, al parecer el namespace es solo una pagina que muestra cuando entras a traves del navegador

Comment: El cambio de namespace no afecta en la forma de invocarlo. Los Web Service REST son un poco diferentes, se invocan agregando el método en la url y no tienen extensión .asmx , ejemplo http://ricotti.com/services/mymetodo/

Comment: @abrahamhs como tema externo, eres de la UNAM de Mex ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenia la duda porque aunque he programado webservice, nunca me ha tocado la parte de la publicación, pero ahora me surge otra duda con la respuesta de Alejandro: Se supone que la url http://localhost:45960/miWebServices.asmx?wsdl es la url y http://localhost:45960/ClientesService.asmx es la documentacion del webService y ahi aparece una parte que dice asi: puede utilizar el nombre de dominio de Internet de su compañía como parte del espacio de nombres aunque muchos espacios de nombres de servicios Web XML parecen direcciones URL, éstos no pueden señalar a recursos reales en Web

Comment: ¿Entonces que documentacion muestra tempuri.org ya que cuando invoco dicha uri me redirecciona a la pagina de bing?

Comment: Por cierto @Elenasys, si soy de la UNAM